# How can I plot with a fewer markers than the data points?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data on x goes from 3MHz to 12MHz, I don't want show all those points on the x-axis instead I want to show an interval of from 3MHz to 12MHz spaced out one 1MHz a part.

[image]

Here is an example code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_array = np.arange(3000000, 12000000)
y_array = np.arange(3000000, 12000000)

plt.plot(x_array, y_array)
plt.show()
```

I want the x-axis first marker to to be 3MHz second marker to be 4MHz and so on up to 12MHz.

Comment: @BigBen I added an example code for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @RyanHaining I am using python3

Answer (score 0):

You can change the matplotlib xticks using the following:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(3000000, 12000000, step=1000000))
```

Defining the step will ensure you have 1MHz space.

You can find more here:

- https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html
- https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Edit:

If you want to have the MHz on the x ticks, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_array = np.arange(3000000, 12000000)
y_array = np.arange(3000000, 12000000)

plt.plot(x_array, y_array)
plt.xticks(ticks=np.arange(3, 13)*1e6, labels=[str(t) + "MHz" for t in np.arange(3, 13)])
plt.show()
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdIM3.png

Otherwise, you can do as mentioned in the other answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_array = np.arange(3000000, 12000000)
y_array = np.arange(3000000, 12000000)

plt.plot(x_array, y_array)
plt.xticks(ticks=np.arange(3, 13)*1e6, labels=np.arange(3, 13))
plt.xlabel("Frequency (MHz)")
plt.show()
```

Output: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc1gb.png2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc1gb.png)

Comment: still shows 1e7. I want to display 1MHz to 12MHz. I don't want the 1e7 same like the picture I posted in the question above.

Comment: Just edited the answer. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have MHz on the x-axis? then use mega Hertz in the definition of the `x` array and multiply by 10⁶ when you use the array as a frequency in a subsequent calculation

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(3, 12, 901)
f = x*1E6
def H(f) : return f

plt.plot(x, H(f))
plt.xticks(range(3, 13))
plt.xlabel('Frequency/MHz')
plt.ylabel('Transfer function')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]